# My iphone app crashes for ios 7

Tags: ios

Finally managed to get an app on the apple store and felt like have achieved my goal 
The app did not sell well - but that is fine - I achieved an app ! 
Now comes the bad part - had never designed it for the latest version of iOS 7 and an end user - who bought the app is complaining it crashes

My question is :

1 How do I contact the end user ?

2 Can I refund the money back through apple ?

3 I did read about getting the crash report through iTunes connect - but I dont see the report - so again - anyway I can get in touch with the end user ?

Finally - i have tested my app on a fourth generation iPod touch which cannot be upgraded to iOS 7 - so I cant even test locally :(

I cannot afford go buy a iPhone 5s / 5c

Any suggestions / thoughts are welcome

Thanks

akila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 How do I contact the end user ?
You can't

2 Can I refund the money back through apple ?
No you can not, they could complain to Apple if they really wanted to.

3 I did read about getting the crash report through iTunes connect - but I don't see the report - so again - anyway I can get in touch with the end user ?
Can't get in touch with the end user. Apple protects their identity for obvious reasons.

Update your app and include the crittercismframework. https://www.crittercism.com/
The framework is free and it will inform you whenever there is a crash along with the stack trace from the crash.  Just follow the instructions on their website.  Do not forget to upload a dsym file to their site when you make an account and are ready to submit to the store again.  Just follow instructions on their website for dsym file too.